# Histogram in R with 1 bin for zeros only

Tags: r, histogram

Is it possible to make a histogram in R with bins of different sizes? I'm working with count data and the zeros need to have their own bin, but the other numbers can be binned into whatever would make sense. A single histogram for all fish counts is fine.

```
fish<-structure(list(num = c(0, 11, 1, 0, 
                             13, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 9, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
                             7, 6, 0, 4, 8, 0, 8, 6, 0)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-50L))
```

Comment: Maybe try: `barplot(table(fish$num))` ?

Comment: Close, but there isn't a way to bin the other numbers too? This is just a made-up dataset, the real one has 142 unique numbers so the bins for each individual number would get really thin.

Comment: Try cut? `barplot(table(cut(fish$num, c(-1, seq(0, 15, 3)))), space = 0)`

Comment: Good enough, haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *cut* to have 0 on its own, then use *seq* to create bins:

```
barplot(table(cut(fish$num, c(0, seq(1, 15, 3)), right = FALSE)), space = 0)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** First bar only includes zeros, see:

```
table(fish$num)
# 0  1  2  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 13 
#31  4  1  1  2  1  2  1  1  4  2 

table(cut(fish$num, c(0, seq(1, 15, 3)), right = FALSE))
#  [0,1)   [1,4)   [4,7)  [7,10) [10,13) 
#     31       5       3       4       5
```

Comment: Does the first bin include 1's? I think this worked better: barplot(table(cut(fish$num, c(-1, seq(0, 15, 3)))), space = 0)

Comment: @Nate see edit, first bar only includes 0s.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the breaks to be whatever you want with the `breaks` parameter to the `hist()` function.  You should combine this with the `freq = TRUE` parameter, or else you'll get a density plot, and the density at zero will be infinite.  The plot doesn't look very good though, because the zero bin has no width:

```
hist(fish$num, breaks = c(0, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20), freq=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure what you'd want to do instead.

[image]

Comment: Maybe change breaks to `c(0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20)` to a get bar for 0 value.

Comment: @zx8754, I think your idea of just giving up on a histogram and using a barplot is better.  I'd probably try to set the labels manually though, e.g. `c("0", "1-5", "6-10", "11-15")`.